# java.util.Properties.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module

Tags: java, sql, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Hello I 'm using Flink SQL Client  1.13.6 to consume data on my local kafka this is my code

```
-- Set the job name 
SET 'pipeline.name' = 'SQL';
    
SET 'execution.runtime-mode' = 'streaming';
SET 'sql-client.execution.result-mode' = 'tableau';
SET 'sql-client.execution.max-table-result.rows' = '10000';
SET 'parallelism.default' = '1';
SET 'pipeline.auto-watermark-interval' = '200';
SET 'pipeline.max-parallelism' = '10';
SET 'table.exec.state.ttl' = '1000'; 
SET 'restart-strategy.type' = 'fixed-delay';
SET 'table.optimizer.join-reorder-enabled' = 'true'; 
SET 'table.exec.spill-compression.enabled' = 'true';
SET 'table.exec.spill-compression.block-size' = '128kb';
    
CREATE TABLE user_created (
  -- one column mapped to the Kafka raw UTF-8 key
  id INT,
  -- a few columns mapped to the Avro fields of the Kafka value
  IMde STRING, 
  p STRING, 
  d STRING, 
  mued STRING    
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'topic-sr',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'key.format' = 'raw',
  'key.fields' = 'id',
  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
  'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://localhost:8081',
  'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY' 
);
    
SELECT * FROM user_created;
```

I got this error :

> [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final long java.util.Properties.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @d6da883

Any Idea what this error means ?

I'm using this version of Java :

- java 20.0.1 2023-04-18
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Are you sure Flink supports Java 20? Have you tried using 11 or 17?